# Can I install producer, broker and consumer on three different machines?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am quite new to kafka. I have the following architecture:

```
1) 2 servers runing application logics and database, can I write kafka producer on these servers wrapped with docker container ?

2) 1 server reserved for kafka broker and zookeeper

3) 1 sever reserved for kafka comsumer
```

I am confusing about

```
1) whether I can run kafka producer, broker and consumer on separate machines ? 

2) How can they communicate ? 

3)Then do I have to install kafka tarball everywhere producer/consumer/broker are running ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can run producers, brokers, and consumers on separate machines.
2. Producers communicate with brokers only, and consumers communicate with brokers only.  That is, the brokers are the intermediary between producers and consumers (hence the name "broker").  The communication between producers, consumers, and brokers happens typically via the Kafka Java or Scala API.  However, there are also native clients for other languages such as C/C++ ([librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka)) as well as an HTTP/REST API ([Confluent kafka-rest](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), see [docs](http://docs.confluent.io/1.0.1/kafka-rest/docs/index.html)).
3. The Kafka tarball must be installed on the brokers.  Whether you need the Kafka tarball also on the producers and/or consumers depends on whether you use any of the included producer/consumer applications such as Kafka's console consumer.  Based on my experience the majority of users write their own producer and/or consumer applications using Kafka's Java/Scala API, and then deploy their custom applications to the desired machines.  In this latter scenario you don't need to install the Kafka tarball also on these machines (i.e. the machines that run the producer/consumer applications).